# Facebook App fails in chrome on POST request when content length > 4306 bytes

Tags: python, facebook, http, post, heroku

I have a facebook app running on heroku derived from the facebook-generated code. The app has been working fine and has no session or login requirements and thus simply returns a static html representation via an HTTP GET request.

However, I have found that if the content length of the HTML returned to be wrapped by facebook's iframe is greater than a certain threshold which appears to be slightly above 4K, the page truncates about halfway through it's content.

The page does render properly up to that point. The app is set to accept HTTP GET and POST and responds to both successfully, unless the request originates from chrome with a logged in user. The same conditions work fine on other browsers. I can see the failing POST request originating from facebook in chrome's debugger. I have not been able to replicate the behavior outside facebook, i.e. the POST requests work fine from my box.

Does anyone know why this POST request would be generated? And why it would fail?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - its very weird

Comment: It only seems to happen (to me) on the first POST after login when you try and get your facebook access token. I hacked round the problem using some redirects

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the channel.html file?

[channel.html](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#channel)